# Django questions: setting the port number and the using an existing database

Tags: django

I have a mini project that I'd like to start on port 2000. How do I do this?

Also, how would I set up the project with an existing database?

What Django books did you find helpful?

Comment: This would be much more useful as three questions; they are unrelated, except all about Django in one way or another.

Comment: Related question for Django books: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230089/two-parter-django-book-recommendation-django-real-world-advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're in the directory you want to be in...

`python ./manager.py runserver 2000`

You can sync a given database by adding the name to `DATABASE_NAME` in settings.py, as well as doing a `python manager.py syncdb` in the terminal.

Also, a quick google would have led you to the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/). I don't understand how you haven't come across this yet?

Comment: Aye! Though I think my answer suffices :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `./manage.py inspectdb` to create a draft of your models.py file to use with the DB.  You will have to separate it out into the appropriate apps, and update field types and relationships as necessary.